# JUnit, dynamically loaded test classes

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, dynamic, junit

I've several dynamically loaded classes (instances of `Class<TestCase>`). I need to run these test via Maven (`mvn verify`). Now I wonder how to do it. All I know is that I can do:

```
Class<TestCase>[] classes = createTests();
JUnitCore junit = new JUnitCore();
junit.addListener(new TextListener(System.out));
junit.run(classes);
```

This just prints results to console. I would like reports for individual tests for all test cases (in Jenkins for example, like with Parameterized runner for example). Could you please point me in right direction? I guess I'll have to create custom runner.

The test classes are generated from 3rd party library. The following unfortunately doesn't work (it does nothing):

```
((TestCase) classes[0].newInstance()).run()
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So I've done some RTFM and came with easy solution. I've created RunListener class that has RunNotifier field, overrided all methods and delegated to equivalent fire* methods in notifier, created custom Runner with following run method:

```
@Override
public void run(RunNotifier runNotifier) {
    try {
        Class<?>[] classes = createTests();
        JUnitCore junit = new JUnitCore();
        junit.addListener(new MyListener(runNotifier));
        junit.run(classes);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and the test is started with this class:

```
@RunWith(MyRunner.class)
public class SomeTest {
}
```